# Saxon - how to call from Java with JBOSS 4.2.3

Tags: java, xml, jboss, saxon, xalan

My current transformer is xalan that came with Jboss and is in the path 'C:\apps\jboss-4.2.3.GA\lib\endorsed\xalan.jar"

My batch file that starts up Jboss and sets all of the variables for it has a section for 'Use Compiling XSLT Processor (XSLTC)'.  It has the current value of:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

If I put my copy of 'saxon9he.jar' into the 'C:\apps\jboss-4.2.3.GA\lib\endorsed\' folder, how would I change the line above in my batch file to call the 'saxon9he.jar' file?

I'm guessing that its being called now by an API?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the value of the TransformerFactory property to

```
net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

There's a risk that this will redirect *all* JAXP operations to use Saxon instead of Xalan, and in a big system like JBoss there's a significant possibility that there will be some application components that assume Xalan will be loaded and fail if they get something else. So a safer approach is to change only the code that you explicitly want to use Saxon, which you can do by replacing the standard JAXP call

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

by

```
TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

Apart from being more robust in ensuring you get the processor you expect, it's also a lot faster to instantiate the class directly rather than using the JAXP classpath search.

Comment: Micheal, that is a great idea to just replace the JAXP call.  I've been searching around but I can't figure out where to add this?  Would this be done in the same batch file where the XSLT processor is called by adding a new line or in a stylesheet?  I'm new to JAVA & XSL so please forgive me, but I'm learning.

Comment: Sorry, without knowing how you currently invoke the transformation it's hard to advise. If you're invoking it from a "batch file" that would be a bit surprising in a JBoss environment, I would have thought.

Comment: well then I'm guess its buried somewhere in a properties file in JBOSS